# Activate or find some way for CEC to trigger HDMI source switch on TV

Tags: windows, hdmi, tv, smart-tv

So recently I set up a mini PC for my mom who is 91 on her TV. The problem is that anything too complex she will never figure out like using the TV remote to go through the available HDMI ports on the TV, it is an older Samsung and it has this Anynet function that seems to make it more confusing than just switching ports.

I notice that when I am connected as a PC to HDMI 2, and she clicks any button on her Roku remote, it instantly takes her to HDMI 1 on which the ROKU is connected.  This is perfect, but getting her back to the PC mode is difficult, it requires the remote.

Is there a way that I can make it so that clicking her mouse or a key on her keyboard will automatically switch her back to the PC HDMI port without having to manually use the remote to select a port?

Comment: you MAY be able to use something like this CEC-USB adapter, which should intercept hdmi CEC events, and send info to a USB port mimicking a keyboard, to wake it up. prolly won't work for powering on, but may work for sleep. https://www.amazon.com/Pulse-Eight-na-USB-HDMI-CEC-Adapter/dp/B005JU6LWM